# Printing line number modulo 1000000

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I have a *very* large compressed file I'm processing using `grep`.

```
zcat blah.gz | grep -e pattern | gzip -c > pattern.gz
```

I'd like to print something to `stderr` for every million or so input lines processed, just to keep track of progress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml).  It defaults to bytes, but there's a switch to make it lines.

Comment: No `zpv` I know of, but since `pv` works with binary data, you can switch it and `zcat`: `pv infile[s] | zcat | grep...`, and because it can tell the size of the file, you should get a determinate progress bar and a fairly accurate ETA.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the grep with:

```
perl -ne 'print if /pattern/; print STDERR "." if $. % 1000000 == 0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Run it through awk:

```
zcat blah.gz | awk 'BEGIN {x = 1}; {if ((x++ % 1000000) == 0) print x " " $0 > "/dev/stderr"; print $0 }' | grep -e pattern | gzip -c > pattern.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mbuffer(1)` tool might be something for you. Quoting some abstract:

> The mbuffer tool is used to buffer data streams and show the I/O rate and
>    summary to the user.  It is especially useful for writing backups to
>    fast tape drives or streaming them over the network.  If used correctly,
>    it can prevent buffer underruns and speed up the whole backup or
>    transfer process.